# using exec() with PHP to run a command

Tags: php, openssl

I am trying to run an openssl command through php which generally works fine but there is one particular command i am trying to run which doesn't work.

Here is the command run manually which works perfectly:

`openssl req -new -newkey rsa:4096 -days 365 -nodes -x509 -subj "/C=US/ST=Denial/L=Springfield/O=Dis/CN=www.example.com" -keyout keyfile.key -out requestfile.csr`

For example, here is an openssl in PHP which DOES work:

`exec('C:/xampp/apache/bin/openssl ecparam -out keyfile.key -name prime256v1 -genkey');`

The same command through PHP does NOT work..

`exec('C:/xampp/apache/bin/openssl req -new -newkey rsa:4096 -days 365 -nodes -x509 -subj \'/C=US/ST=Denial/L=Springfield/O=Dis/CN=www.example.com\' -keyout keyfile.key -out requestfile.csr');`

I am thinking there is something wrong with the parts in double quotes "/C=" may not be getting interpreted properly. if I make similar openssl calls through php without the parts in "" the command executes fine.

Would like a knowledgeable php person to check if its being passed correct or not

Please don't suggest to me to use PHP's built in openssl library, i am well aware of them and I have all that working on a different project but I need to use exec() to create ECC keys which is not available in PHP's built in openssl library.

Comment: Are you running this from the command prompt with "php filename.php"?

Comment: i have a php file with the exec() command inside and i simply run that php page in a web browser.. the command without exec() is the one i run through command line and works

Comment: Can you try running the php script from the command prompt instead of a web browser using "php filename.php"

Comment: i don't understand.. how can i run a php script from command prompt ?

Comment: if it helps, i am on windows.. `'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Comment: https://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.commandline.php

Comment: That means php is not in your path, you will need to specify full path to php first: "c:\path\to\php filename.php"

Comment: You should look into the output and return value of `exec`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Comment: @ecnepsnai thanks for the link.. i understand what you mean now.. i need to try execute with php.exe - i will try that and report back

Comment: using php.exe to run the php script file i got this error `Subject does not start with '/'. problems making Certificate Request`

Comment: Try to manually type the code that Barmar gave you instead of copying and pasting. It could be that the quotes (or other symbols) are not standard plain text quotes.

Comment: @kojow, i did but doesnt work.. bizarre if i run through command line `C:\xampp\php>php -f C:\xampp\htdocs\labs\test4\openssl3.php` it works and the file are generated

Comment: So what wasn't working from the command line? Could it be that your web server has no permission to write a file in the directory?

Comment: it cant be permissions but another command does work in the browser `exec('C:/xampp/apache/bin/openssl ecparam -out keyfile.key -name request.csr -genkey');` the only difference between this one and the one that doesnt work is the one that doesnt work containts the double quotes as mentioned in my post

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Windows `cmd.exe` allows you to use single quotes to quote an argument, you have to use double quotes.

```
exec('C:/xampp/apache/bin/openssl req -new -newkey rsa:4096 -days 365 -nodes -x509 -subj "/C=US/ST=Denial/L=Springfield/O=Dis/CN=www.example.com" -keyout keyfile.key -out requestfile.csr');
```

Comment: ultimately, the command needs to reference string variables to build the request i.e. `exec('C:/xampp/apache/bin/openssl req -new -key '.$keyfile.' -out C:/xampp/htdocs/labs/test4/testcsr.txt -subj \'/C='.$country.'/ST='.$state.'/L='.$location.'/OU='.$orgUnit.'/O='.$org.'/CN='.$commonName.'\'');` but again, cant seem to get it to work from a browser =(

Comment: unfortunately not.. php log file remains at 0KB after running the php file in browser

Comment: Let's not get ahead of ourselves. First try to solve the problem without variables, then you can add the variables. So did you check the PHP error log? Or add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the beginning of your script?

Comment: i agree, its best to troubleshoot without any variables for now.. so i added the error_reporting(E_ALL); and re-ran the php file and still no errors/warnings on page and php log remains at 0KB

Comment: If it's not reporting an error, I'm not sure why it wouldn't be executing. Are you sure you're looking in the right place for the output files?

Comment: i am certainly looking in the right places.. i have the directories specified `exec('C:/xampp/apache/bin/openssl req -new -newkey rsa:4096 -days 365 -nodes -x509 -subj "/C=US/ST=Denial/L=Springfield/O=Dis/CN=www.example.com" -keyout C:/xampp/htdocs/labs/test4/keyfile.key -out C:/xampp/htdocs/labs/test4/requestfile.csr');`

Comment: Also hard to tell on here, but make sure everything is on a single line with no spaces in places where there shouldn't be spaces.